# AngularJS - MVC ASP.NET Directory Structure

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

This is more of a general inquiry. I am looking to start a personal website as a side project using ASP.NET MVC 5/WebAPI. For my front end (Javascript) I want to use AngularJS. I have been reading tons of articles and they all suggested the best way to structure your files is to put the html, service/controller all together in the same folder. I am not sure if this is best practice for ASP.NET MVC.

What are some things that you guys can recommend to achieve clean and reusable code.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the kind of question likely to draw downvotes and/or close votes.  It's entirely subjective, and there is no one right answer.  The "Right" way for one developer is going to be the "Wrong" way for someone else.  It also could vary per project, depending on how much you use MVC Razor views vs angular SPA, and if you are more frontend or backend focused.

Comment: honestly, unless you are working in an enterprise level project with thousands of files, you're probably better off just trying to solve the problem at hand than worry about if it's the most efficient solution.  Developer paralysis is pretty easy to get sucked in to, where you spend more time worrying about the quality of your code than the actual problem you are trying to solve...

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to create a simply web application using angularjs, mvc and RESTful Web Service, I named it is “manage customer”.
List of features:

- List customer
- Edit customer
- Create new customer
- Delete customer

List of projects of “manage customer” application:

- CustomerEntities (EntityFramework 6.0.0.0)
- CustomerDAL (c# classes)
- CustomerBLL (c# classes)
- CustomerAPI (RESTful web service)
- CustomerUI (AngularJs, MVC)

Here is solution structure:

[image]

More detail and source here [AngularJs MVC](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/tutorial-32-angularjs-works-with-web-api.html)